# Looking for short story about time-traveler coming back from Jupiter to destroy computer that governs humanity

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, comics

I am looking for a short story comic book about an astronaut who builds an artificial intelligent computer and then goes on a mission to Jupiter.

When the astronauts land on one of Jupiter's moons, they see other humans already there much to their surprise. They believed they were the first mission to Jupiter. The humans bring the astronauts back to Earth, and on the way back, they learn they were displaced forward in time by several decades or more. There are now settlers on Mars, Mercury, many asteroids, and elsewhere in the Solar System.

The time-traveling astronauts discover Earth is governed by a super intelligent computer. The computer recognizes one of the astronauts as its creator, whom it believed died on a mission to Jupiter long ago. The astronaut knows things about the computer that nobody else would know. The computer can't comprehend why its creator is still alive and promptly crashes.

I think the story was written sometime from the late 1950's through early 1970's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102392/astronauts-on-europa-moon-time-shift-future-gravity-intelligent-computer-a?rq=1  (Wish I had an answer - sounds like a good read.)

Comment: @Ghotir Yes, that looks very familiar. Go ahead and close this as a duplicate.

Comment: I tried to close my own question as a duplicate of another. Unfortunately, StackExchange would not let me close this because it says the other question does not have an answer yet. How odd!

Comment: Ah... the other one doesn't have an answer either.  Ah well... with two questions out there, double the chances someone will find it?